# C++ Debug Assertion Error Confusion

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, object, vector

I'm receiving an error on this line

`sort(moveprob.begin(), moveprob.end(), objectSort);`

Moveprob= `vector<object> moveprob;`

OBJECT: `

```
struct object {
public:
    int move;
    double prob;

    int getMove();
    double getProb();
};

int object::getMove() {
    return move;
}

double object::getProb() {
    return prob;
}

bool objectSort(const object &o1, const object &o2) {
    if (o1.prob != o2.prob) {
        return o1.prob < o2.prob;
    }
}`
```

It say's it is a debug assertion error `invalid operator<` and then it gives a page line that doesn't match up to anything that could be causing this error. It does mention `algorithm`. Any and all ideas are much appreciated because I'm completely lost. Thanks!

Comment: `objectSort` doesn't return a value when `o1.prob` equals `o2.prob`; that will get you into all kinds of trouble.

Comment: what should I have it return? and the odd thing is, the program its in works when it's stand alone, but when I try to impliment it into another program i get this error

Comment: Well, if both `prob`s are equal, the first one is not smaller than the second one, do the result should be `false`. In fact, you can just get rid of the `if`. General advice: Turn on a reasonable compiler warning level and fix all the warnings you get. gcc for example would have told you that "control reaches end of non-void function" (or smth. like that).